# Ignore elements where the condition cannot be met with .mask()

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following series'

```py
s = pd.Series([0,1,'random',2,3,4])

s2 = pd.Series([5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

How can I use `s.mask` to return a series where every even number in `s` is replaced by `s2`, and elements in s that can't get evaluated per the condition get ignored (e.g. 'random')?

I tried this which gave an `ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self`

```py
def is_even_if_is_number(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return x % 2 == 0
    return False        

s.mask(lambda x: is_even_if_is_number(x), s2)
```

I want an output of this

```
0         5
1         1
2    random
3         8
4         3
5        10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create mask first and then pass to [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
#even number 
m = (np.arange(len(s)) % 2 == 0) & pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce').notna()

#even integer
#m = (np.arange(len(s)) % 2 == 0) & s.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, int))
out = s.mask(m, s2)
print (out)
0         5
1         1
2    random
3         2
4         9
5         4
dtype: object
```